# How to access a private member inside a static void* function

Tags: c++, boost, pthreads

File:Service.hpp

```
class Service
{
private:
         boost::unordered_map<std::string,int> m_mapModuleType2FD;
         void ProcessRequest();
public:
         static void* KeepAlive(void* arg);

};
```

File:Service.cpp:

In the function Process Request I update the map

```
void Service::ProcessRequest()
{
       m_mapModuleType2FD["ak"] = 1;
       LaunchKeepAlive();           

}


void Service::LaunchKeepAlive()
{
 pthread_create( & m_ptKeepAliveThreadID, NULL, Service::KeepAlive, NULL );
}
```

Now Inside KeepAlive I tried to look for the updated value

```
void * Service::KeepAlive(void* arg)
{
    boost::unordered_map<std::string,int>::iterator itrDummy;
    itrDummy = m_mapModuleType2FD.find("AK"); --- Line 420
}
```

Where in I get and Error

error: Line 420 .invalid use of member 'Service::m_mapModuleType2FD' in static member function

I am kinda new to C++ ..So any Inputs would be highly appreciated

Comment: So, what do you plan for your `CExtIOService` class. Is it kind of a `singleton`-like object (single instance in the whole program) ? Or do you need more than one ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A function declared `static` in a class isn't associated with any instance of this class (i.e. there's no `this` pointer accessible within its body).

Thus you just can't access any non-static member variable (be it private, protected or public, it doesn't matter).

Either make your function non-static (and call it on an instance of your class), or make the `boost::unordered_map` static.

(As I don't know what you really want to do, you'll have to figure out which method fits your need)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access `m_mapModuleType2FD` from a static context, you need this member to be made static as well :

```
class CExtIOService
{
private:
         static boost::unordered_map<std::string,int> m_mapModuleType2FD;
         void ProcessRequest();
public:
         static void* KeepAlive(void* arg);

};
```

and access it statically :

```
itrDummy = CExtIOService::m_mapModuleType2FD.find(...);
```

Which might not be what you want, since `m_mapModuleType2FD` would be the same reference shared by every instance of the class `CExtIOService`. That is to say that modifying it from one instance will change the map for all the instances you've got.

It depends on what your plans are...

Answer (score 0):

You could pass the instance as parameter to the static member:

```
class Service
{
public:
     typedef boost::unordered_map<std::string,int> map_t;
private:
     map_t m_mapModuleType2FD;
     void ProcessRequest();


public:
     static void* KeepAlive(Service* this_, void* arg); // fake this pointer
     map_t* getMap() { return m_mapModuleType2FD; }
};

// ....
void * Service::KeepAlive(Service* this_, void* arg)
{
    map_t::iterator itrDummy = this_->getMap()->find("AK");
                             //^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
}
```

And call it like this:

```
Service instance;
Service::KeepAlive(&instance, argument);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your static member just doesn't belong to one specific instance of the class, there is no `this` pointer available.

That is exactly what the `void* arg` is for. You can smuggle a `this` pointer into your static `StaticKeepAlive(void*)` function, and then call on to a non-static `RealKeepAlive()` function:

```
class CExtIOService
{
private:
    boost::unordered_map<std::string,int> m_mapModuleType2FD;
    void ProcessRequest();

    void RealKeepAlive();
    static void* StaticKeepAlive(void* arg);
public:
    void LaunchKeepAlive();
};

void CExtIOService::RealKeepAlive()
{
    boost::unordered_map<std::string,int>::iterator itrDummy;
    itrDummy = m_mapModuleType2FD.find("AK");
}

void *CExtIOService::StaticKeepAlive(void* arg)
{
    CExtIOService* ptr = reinterpret_cast<CExtIOService*>(arg);
    arg->RealKeepAlive();
    return NULL;
}

void CExtIOService::LaunchKeepAlive()
{
    pthread_create( & m_ptKeepAliveThreadID, NULL, CExtIOService::StaticKeepAlive, 
                    reinterpret_cast<void*>(this) );
}
```